# Installing TensorFlow 1.0.0 on Ubuntu 22.04 [WSL] with Python 3.6.15 Virtual Environment

Tags: virtualbox, python, tensorflow

I am running Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS with the default Python version being 3.10. Additionally, I have installed Python 3.6.15 and created a virtual environment with Python 3.6.15. In this virtual environment, the Python version is 3.6.15.

My goal is to install TensorFlow version 1.0.0 within this virtual environment. However, when I attempt to install it using the standard pip command:

`pip install tensorflow==1.0.0`

I encounter the following error:

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.0.0 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.0.0

I have also attempted to install TensorFlow 1.0.0 directly from a wheel file downloaded from the source using the following command:

`pip install tensorflow-1.0.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl`

However, this results in the following error:

**tensorflow-1.0.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.**

What steps can I take to successfully install TensorFlow 1.0.0 on Ubuntu 22.04 with a Python 3.6.15 virtual environment? I appreciate any guidance or solutions to resolve this issue.

Comment: I'd check your system has all security fixes applied asap, as your provided details (*if accurate*) show you haven't. You can refer to https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/08/11/ubuntu-22-04-3-lts-released/ for the ISO release date of 22.04.3 (*you say you're still at 22.04.2*) but installed systems upgraded **before** the ISO release date... eg. the 22.04.4 HWE kernel has already rolled out for most users, yet we're not at 22.04.4 yet (*ie. those upgrades are rolling out now; with the version only showing 22.04.4 when all are out*)

Comment: Can you elaborate it more, its WSL, and its release is 22.4.02 should I update my ubuntu?

Comment: Your question doesn't mention WSL, and I have no useful experience with WSL so I cannot comment there. A full 22.04 install that has all upgrades applied will respond as 22.04.3 currently.